# how to do a Unit Test with Junit and mockito in java on methods that I need to test

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

I'm new to Junit and Mockito Testing in Java, can someone give me an example or an idea of ​​how I can test a method that basically reads a file and at the same time receives a date:

```
public List<String> readFile(String date) {
    String dateConverted = FormatsDates.fileAEDateFormat(date);
    GetFiles getFiles = new GetFiles();
    String readDataFile = getFiles.getFileAE(dateConverted);
    
    List<String> obtainList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (!readDataFile.isEmpty()) {
        try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(readDataFile); 
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {

            String separator;
            String line;
            int cont = 0;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                cont++;
                if (cont > 1) {
                    line = line.replace(ConstantsFiles.LIN_WIT_SPA, ConstantsFiles.REP_SPA_LIN);
                    separator = line.substring(POS_CLTE, LONG_CLTE);
                    logger.info("Longitud correcta: " + separator);
                    
                    if (separator.length() == Integer.parseInt(ConstantsFiles.LENGTH_CLIENT)) {
                        obtainList.add(separator);
                        
                    } else {
                        logger.error("Longitud incorrecta: " + separator);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            logger.error("Error, archivo no encontrado: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error("Error de lectura, archivo Ejecutivos Facultados: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        return obtainList;
    }
    return obtainList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class YourClassTest {

    @Mock
    private GetFiles getFiles;
    
    private YourClass yourClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        yourClass = new YourClass();
        yourClass.setGetFiles(getFiles);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        // Clean up any resources used by the test
    }

    @Test
    public void testReadFileWithValidData() throws IOException {
        // Step 1: Prepare mock objects
        String testDate = "2023-04-25";
        String dateConverted = FormatsDates.fileAEDateFormat(testDate);
        String readDataFile = "test_file.txt";
        List<String> expectedList = new ArrayList<>();
        expectedList.add("separator1");
        expectedList.add("separator2");
        
        when(getFiles.getFileAE(dateConverted)).thenReturn(readDataFile);

        // Step 2: Call the method
        List<String> resultList = yourClass.readFile(testDate);

        // Step 3: Assert expected results
        assertNotNull(resultList);
        assertEquals("Expected list size", expectedList.size(), resultList.size());
        assertEquals("Expected list elements", expectedList, resultList);
        
        // Step 4: Verify mock interactions
        verify(getFiles).getFileAE(dateConverted);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testReadFileWithEmptyDataFile() throws IOException {
        // Step 1: Prepare mock objects
        String testDate = "2023-04-25";
        String dateConverted = FormatsDates.fileAEDateFormat(testDate);
        String readDataFile = "";
        List<String> expectedList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        when(getFiles.getFileAE(dateConverted)).thenReturn(readDataFile);

        // Step 2: Call the method
        List<String> resultList = yourClass.readFile(testDate);

        // Step 3: Assert expected results
        assertNotNull(resultList);
        assertEquals("Expected list size", expectedList.size(), resultList.size());
        
        // Step 4: Verify mock interactions
        verify(getFiles).getFileAE(dateConverted);
    }

    // Additional tests and edge cases can be added here
}
```

You can try something like this.

Comment: Muhammad Arsil Khan where does it come from yourClass.setGetFiles(getFiles); this line gives me an error.

Comment: It is a template, replace test class and its method with yours.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).