# How to test a method using Junit and Mockito in Java on a method that creates a file in such a path

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

I want to test a method using JUnit and Mockito in Java this method basically reads a path and creates a file, and if the file exists delete it and create it again, any examples you can help me with?

Here is the method I want to test:

```
public String getFilePE(String fecha) {
    String fileName = null;
    String filePath = null;
    File file = null;

    try {
        logger.info("Generando archivo para PE");
        fileName = ConstantsFiles.FILE_NAME_PE + fecha + ConstantsFiles.FILE_EXTENSION;
        filePath = ConstantsFiles.FILE_PATH_PE + fileName;
        logger.info(filePath);
        
        file = new File(filePath);
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            logger.info("Archivo creado con exito " + file.getName());
        } else {
            Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(filePath));
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error("Error, el archivo no se pudo generar: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post the same question over and over: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76106454/how-to-do-a-unit-test-with-junit-and-mockito-in-java-on-methods-that-read-a-path), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105752/how-to-do-a-unit-test-with-junit-and-mockito-in-java-on-methods-that-prefer-date), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76103872/how-to-do-a-unit-test-with-junit-and-mockito-in-java-on-methods-that-i-need-to-t), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76103154/how-to-make-a-unit-test-with-junit-and-mockito-in-java)

Comment: If you don't get an answer, try to refine your question, include what you have already tried and how that didn't work. See [ask].

Comment: It's also not clear to me what you want to test. That the file name gets built correctly? That errors get logged? That the file must not exist? Something else?

Comment: Robert With respect to your first comment, I changed the question to see if it explained a little better and basically to this question that I updated, I only need to verify that the file is really being created in such a path and that if it exists, delete it and create it again

Comment: Robert Regarding your second comment and the question that was before this one that I just updated, if it only required checking that the file really exists in such a path and likewise checking the case in which it does not exist, then return empty

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `file.createNewFile()` calls

```
 @Test
 public void testGetFilePE() {
 File file = mock(File.class)
 yourMockedService.getFilePE("String"); 
 verify(file).createNewFile();
}
```

Then if you need to test all cases. Like `else` statement or `catch` block. You will need to simulate throwing errors and mock `if` statemement

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you use the file system in your test. This adds an external dependency that you should not have in a unit test. File systems may or may not be in the right state, they have caches which may trip your test randomly, and they are generally much slower than working with memory only. The best thing would be to refactor the code (or actually the callers of the code under test) to work with `InputStream` and `OutputStream` which you can easily use with `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` in real life, but swap against `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` respectively. If your code creates an empty file, nothing guarantees that the file will still exist or still be empty when the caller of your code tries to use it. Separating file creation from actually using the file opens you up for a [symlink race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink_race).

That said, if you want to test that the code under test creates or deletes files, you'll have to ask the file system, or mock the file system.

### Using a real file system (I'd avoid this)

Use the same `File` methods as the code under test, like the code below. Note that this is untested code, as you didn't provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```java
@Test
public void createsFileIfItDoesNotExist() throws InterruptedException {
    String fecha = "2023-04-26";

    String path = getFilePE(fecha);

    assertEquals(ConstantsFiles.FILE_NAME_PE + fecha + ConstantsFiles.FILE_EXTENSION, path, "wrong path");

    Thread.sleep(5 * 1000); // ms
    File expected = new File(path);
    assertTrue(expected.exists(), "should have create a file");
    assertEquals(0, expected.length(), "file should be empty");
}
```

Some remarks:

- The assertion for the path is a lot like the code under test; I'd probably hard-code the path in the test, or remove the check completely. But this depends on what you want to test.
- The `Thread.sleep` is there to allow the file system to reflect the changes. Currently it sleeps for 5 seconds, which is already bad enough as most tests should run much faster than that. If the test is flaky (sometimes passes, sometimes fails), you may need to increase this.
- You may be able to decrease the chance of tests interfering with each other by using JUnit5's [@TempDir](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/io/TempDir.html) annotation (see [this Java Magazine blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/working-and-unit-testing-with-temporary-files-in-java)), but that requires that you pass in the constant parts of the path you build, instead of just using some global constants.
- For other tests, make sure you use different dates, or one test may clobber the files from another test, or files may unexpectedly exist (the joy of a shared dependency).

### Mocking the file system

Again, untested code:

```java
@Test
public void createsFileIfItDoesNotExist() {
    File f = mock(File.class);
    when(f.createNewFile).thenReturn(true);
    getFilePE("2023-04-26");
    verify(f).createNewFile("/expected/path/to/the/file");
}
```

With whatever style you go, write more tests along those lines, e.g., with creating the file and writing something to it (or faking it exists), and then checking that it got truncated, or whatever else you want to test.